# To remove ajax cache busting parameters appended in AEM for a particular clientlibs

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, aem

For one particular AEM component clientlibs, we are getting the jquery cache busting parameters attached to the clientlib and also its dependencies.
**clientlibs_promotionalmarquee.58cb5599a134750c2d25d6157efd1143.js?*=1503901717308
localization.7e941d18b8383ca6f8b40363c9d3680e.js?*=1503901717307
jquery.fb50358df4c2bd6aa6e1dd5b0d9b9d29.js?_=1503901717306**

[See Image for clientlib properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8WaL.png)

[Clientlib include in html image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9znT.png)

Any clientlibs included in that particular html gets those parameters appended to them.
No changes have been done through code to achieve this,Is there any other way it could happen?

Comment: Is it getting rewritten? I use ACS Commons Versioned Clienlibs to write in the hash https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/versioned-clientlibs/index.html

Comment: The hash that prepends the extension is most likely added by ACS Commons Versioned Clienlibs and my guess is the cache busting parameters are added by a module on your web server (i.e. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/)

Comment: ACS versioned clientlibs is a different case,In my scenarios the clientlibs request in the network tab is getting appened with ?_=151243414123123 which happens with the cache false parameter in an ajax jquery request.